# Meteor Facebook Profile Picture not Displaying

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

On first sign I have the following code:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
  if (typeof(user.services.facebook) != "undefined") {
      user.services.facebook.picture = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large";
  }
  return user;
});
```

Which results in the following URL string

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[myfacebookid]/picture/?type=large
```

Yet when it renders that url and returns

```
<img scr="http://graph.facebook.com/[myfacebookid]/picture/?type=large" alt="My Name">
```

All I see is a broken image. How can I pull this in so that it renders the facebook profile picture?

Comment: the url looks correct...

Comment: That's what's so troubling. I know the url is correct but the image remains broken. I was hoping someone could tell me to pre-render with ajax or something because this is just pulling hair at this point.

Comment: not sure, I've used facebook pics in meteor apps before with no problem.  Possibly the problem is with something else in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a helper function based off of the Facebook ID of the user to grab the image on the server. I notice my url has /picture? and your has /picture/?  Hope this helps.

```
userPicHelper: function() {
    if (this.profile) {
        var id = this.profile.facebookId;
        var img = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture?type=square&height=160&width=160';
        return img;
    }
},
```

I don't know how I missed this before, but is this the src attribute on the image tag is actually written as scr:

```
<img scr=
```

Should be...

```
<img src=
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the slash and no difference. I have not tried it as a helper yet, so I'll do that. In your helper, what does "this" refer to?

Comment: This refers to the data context.

Comment: I edited my response after looking over your code again... hope it helps

Comment: holy crap what an obvious mistake haha. you rule, thanks for being my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You have http instead of https.
So:
`"https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture/?type=large";`

This was my problem.